# Pausing YouTube iFrame API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have a Youtube video embedded in a slideshow that I would like to pause when the user clicks on an `img` thumbnail:

```
<li><iframe width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjUz8IT0CYg?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="my-video"></iframe></li>
```

I've been over the Youtube API but I'm confused how to get things started.

Does the API JS load automatically when I append `?enablejsapi` to the end of the YouTube `video id`?

Here is my JS:

```
var player1 = document.getElementById('my-video');

$('img').click(function () {
  player1.pauseVideo();
})
```

**EDIT:**

Here's what I did based on Matt's answer below, for anyone wondering:

```
<li><iframe width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XjUz8IT0CYg?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="player-1"></iframe></li>

<li><iframe width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HVhSasnVjMQ?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="player-2"></iframe></li>
```

And then my JS:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Create YouTube player(s) after the API code downloads.
var player1;
var player2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player-1');
    player2 = new YT.Player('player-2');
}
```

Then in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slideshow-1 img").click(function () {
        player1.stopVideo();
    });

    $(".slideshow-2 img").click(function () {
        player2.stopVideo();
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, to start with, your missing a closing iframe tag...

Comment: @A.M.K heh, thanks. Unfortunately for me, that is indeed present in my code and not the problem. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Appending `?enablejsapi` in the embed string does not automatically include the API code. It only registers that particular embed with the API.

You want to read the first example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

1. The asynchronous code snippet downloads and executes the YT iframe API
2. `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` is fired when the API is ready
3. Create a new `YT.Player` object
4. Your code can now call `pauseVideo()` on your player object

You will most likely want to disable any events on your img until `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` has been fired.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to keep your JS in external file use:

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="player1" class="ytplayer" width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HVhSasnVjMQ?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="player2" class="ytplayer" width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HVhSasnVjMQ?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
var yt_int, yt_players={},
    initYT = function() {
        $(".ytplayer").each(function() {
            yt_players[this.id] = new YT.Player(this.id);
        });
    };
$.getScript("//www.youtube.com/player_api", function() {
    yt_int = setInterval(function(){
        if(typeof YT === "object"){
            initYT();
            clearInterval(yt_int);
        }
    },500);
});
```

**Control Video**

```
yt_players['player_id'].playVideo();
```

The reason I do it this way is because I have the videos loading dynamically via the CMS and they open in an overlay. I set the close/open overlay functions to play/pause the video.

Comment: Thank you so much for this snippet. I can't believe how hard it is to get access to that player object. This was just what I needed

Comment: based on your code snippet here is an http://jsfiddle.net/av359/ example thanks a lot

Comment: God bless you my friend!

Comment: The url to getScript needs the "https:". Stackoverflow removes it from code snippets.

Comment: @JSet it actually doesn't. That is a protocol relative url, you can read more here: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/  (note: protocol relative url's require you're on a web server, it will not work on a local file)

Comment: Just thought I'd share this little extra snippet which demonstrates how you can mute the youtube video on load. ' var yt_int, yt_players={},
           initYT = function() {
            $(".ytplayer").each(function() {
             yt_players[this.id] = new YT.Player(this.id, {
              
              events: {
               'onReady': function(event) {
                event.target.mute();
               }
              }
              
             });
            });
           }; '

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution:

```
<iframe id="player1" class="ytplayer" width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HVhSasnVjMQ?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="player2" class="ytplayer" width="430" height="241" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HVhSasnVjMQ?enablejsapi=1&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and

```
$('.ytplayer').each(function(){
    //this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*')
});
```