# Pause Youtube Video upon Opening New Browser Window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

I've been banging my head on trying to get my embedded youtube playlist to stop (preferrably pause) when the user opens a new browser window via a link from within the webpage. This link goes to another page which also automatically starts a video (nobody wants two videos playing at once). This is the bare bones code I have thus far. Thanks for the help.

```
<iframe width="452" height="278" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL3NaSh-osYfmAc4IUijQN1aJGDehZepVQ&autoplay=1?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the link onClick, [call pause to the Youtube control](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference%29) and continue with opening the link. More like this:

Remove the href from your link, and set a #mark. Set an id (let's suppose is myLink).
Catch the click on the link:

```
 $("#myLink").click(function(e) {
   //call pause on your Youtube control. See this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522499/335905 
   // as long as you are not calling e.preventDefault(), the link should continue opening as expected. 

   });
```

Comment: The problem with this is, `window.open` is treated like a popup window, and may even be initially blocked.

Comment: so long as you are not calling `e.preventDefault()`, the link should continue opening as expected, so `window.open` may not even be necessary.

Comment: right about both comments. Edited and added your feedback, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm not a programmer by any means. I'll probably have to be given the entire code. I'm getting pretty lost in trying to put things together on my end.

Comment: Also, I probably should have added, that the link is not in text form, it's actually a picture which opens into a new link in another browser window.