# Is there a way to pause Youtube video in a iframe with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pause Youtube video in a iframe with jQuery? Is it possible or I have to use iframe api?

Comment: Definitely maybe? :D

Comment: you can't do it with javascript because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522291/pausing-youtube-iframe-api-in-javascript