# Pause youtube video when slide the next item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I am using bootstrap slider on my page. I need to pause the currently playing video when slider moves to the next one.
I tried using youtube callback but it doesnt seems like working, may be my way of applying is not right.

here is what I have used

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('div.carousel-inner div.active').attr('id', 'current');
    });

    function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args='') {

        if (window.jQuery && frame_id instanceof jQuery) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
        var iframe = document.getElementById(frame_id);
        if (iframe && iframe.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IFRAME') {
            iframe = iframe.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        }
        if (iframe) {
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                "event": "command",
                "func": func,
                "args": args || [],
                "id": frame_id
            }), "*");
        }

        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('div.carousel-inner div.item').attr('id', '');
            $('div.carousel-inner div.active').attr('id', 'current');
        });
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/401/)**

Comment: kindly refer http://9bugs.in/pause-youtube-video-within-iframe-using-external-button-click-in-javascript-or-jquery-268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/403/)

I modified your HTML as follows.

```
- onclick="callPlayer("current","pauseVideo")"
+ onclick="callPlayer('current','pauseVideo')"
```

And I change LOAD TYPE from `onLoad` to `No wrap in <head>`.

However, You should attach Click Event with jQuery `on` method.

Comment: same here.. unable to pause the 2nd slide video when moved to the 3rd slide.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/407/ However, you should review structure.

Comment: That worked but could u pls explain what was the issue?

Comment: Hmm, I think the prev video will not pause when you use auto-play. If I have time, I'll write a refactored code.

Comment: @user3932810 I'm sorry to be late. Please make sure my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/408/

Comment: Thanks.. but another problem with it.. Incase if we have an image in the slider, it is affecting the carousel movement. keep clicking on the right arrow and it doesnt work when it reached image slide. check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/410/

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the slide contains an image. you should check iframe or image on `slide.bs.carousel` event. http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/412/ However, your reply is off-topic.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to mention that in my question. Slider contains both image and videos. How do we get it work in this case?? in your recent fiddle(with image) video is not pausing when moved to next slide. Please have a look n suggest.

Comment: Sorry. I mistook. Please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/412/ . I needed to use `currentVideo.is('iframe')`.

Comment: this still not pausing the video :(

Comment: Got it.. I added `currentVideo.is('iframe')` as u suggested and it worked http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/413/ Thank you :)

Comment: can u pls chk this thumbnail issue of the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860667/youtube-embeded-video-not-displaying-thumbnail

Answer (score 2):

I binded the carousel controls in the javascript portion instead of having it inline in the html.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // ...

    $(".carousel-control").click(function() {
        callPlayer('current','pauseVideo');
    });
});
```

See the revised [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/402/).

Comment: in this, when u slide to send slide 1st slide video gets paused but u play 2nd slide video and move to 3rd slide then 2nd slide video is still playing

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. http://jsfiddle.net/2q99udgk/406/  I give each carousel item a different class (foo1, foo2, foo3). Then in callPlayer, I alert the `iframe.className`. Look at how it shows `foo1` two times in a row.

Comment: but what is the solution for pausing the 2nd slide video when moved to 3rd slide?

Comment: Any idea why the video is removing the thumbnail image and showing the black screen while sliding back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the youtube iframe api. For that you have to append `?enablejsapi` to your iframe source. You should maybe follow the tutorial from youtube.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

1. onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() will be fired
2. now create a yt player object
3. your code can now call pauseVideo() on your object

Also answered in this question: [Pausing YouTube iFrame API in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522291/pausing-youtube-iframe-api-in-javascript)