# Make iframe video controller like play, pause

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to make controller for iframe by placing button: **play**, **pause**. But am unable to understand why i am getting fail everytime. I am using javascript but fail to understand the reason: here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
    <button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br>


    <iframe id="myVideo" width="100%" height="419" src="small.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script>
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

        function playVid() {
            vid.play();
        }

        function pauseVid() {
            vid.pause();
        }
    </script>

    <p>Video courtesy of <a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I also have seen thes post:
[Pausing YouTube iFrame API in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522291/pausing-youtube-iframe-api-in-javascript)

[Stop all playing iframe videos on click a link javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598423/stop-all-playing-iframe-videos-on-click-a-link-javascript)

as for example but fail......

Comment: why do you use an iframe to play your video?

Comment: i am also trying to use hls stream aka m3u8 which <video> does not support in older browser

Comment: like: <iframe id="video" width="100%" height="419" src="http://videoplayer.vodobox.com/vodobox_player.php?vid=http://109.123.70.72:1935/live/ptvsports/samitv.m3u8&img=&play=?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: video tag works from IE8 upwards - do you really need to support 8 and below?

Comment: yeah. I want to support every browser as i am seeing all type of users.

Comment: any solution possible. I am searching as well.

Comment: try setting this attribute <iframe .... controls="2" ...

Comment: i wrote in this way:
<iframe controls="2" id="myVideo" width="100%" height="419" src="small.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: is my javascript correct? or wrong?

Comment: I tested it in a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dkmrmymf/1/ and it works for me. When you don't really need custom buttons you can use this method. Note: you need to change the source to a real source in order to see and use the default controls

Comment: very strange. Nothing is working for me even i place this: <iframe autoplay="1" controls="2" id="myVideo" width="100%" height="419" src="small.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: and in jsfiddle i placed live stream url and still not working