# Pause YouTube video with window.onbeforeunload so it doesn't overlap audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have a website with a custom audio recording when trying to leave the site. This is working fine, but the issue is that I also have a YouTube video that overlaps my audio.

I want to pause or mute my YouTube video when my audio starts playing, this is triggered by `window.onbeforeunload`

I tried to do so like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
         player.pauseVideo();
       }
```

I already implemented the YouTube API and everything is working fine, but the pause is not being triggered. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start from [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started).

Then you can follow these steps from an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522291/pausing-youtube-iframe-api-in-javascript).

> 1. The asynchronous code snippet downloads and executes the YT iframe API
> 2. `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` is fired when the API is ready
> 3. Create a new `YT.Player` object
> 4. Your code can now call `pauseVideo()` on your player object
>
> You will most likely want to disable any events on your img until
>   `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` has been fired.

Refer also to this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/gNF6q/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

AS the YouTube api is an asynchronous load, you can not call it from anything that has already executed.

My suggestion would be to put a "var" of "audio_playing" into your window.onbeforeunload function and make it global. Then set it to true or false respectively.

In your YT api code. have the YT player look for that "var" and set the play state accordingly.